# is there a formal way to say let "x be the i-th greatest element in a subset of [n]"

Tags: soft-question

I was wondering if there is a formal way to say that "x is the i-th greatest element in a subset of $[n]$" (or maybe is this formal?).

For example if i have $M=\{2,3,5,7,11,20\}$, how can I say that if I take 7, this is the 3rd greatest element in $M$. And in general, if I want to refer to some arbitrary x, how should I say this?

What iI am actually doing is trying to build a function that takes the i-th greatest element of a subset of $[n]$ to some value, but I want to make it as formal as possible when referring to that element.

Thanks.

Comment: This is related to “order statistics.” On the Wikipedia page for that, given $M=\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ of a set, they use $X_{(i)}$ for the $i$th largest number. But that notation comes from probability, it is not, as far as I know, common outside of probability and statistics.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That notation is for the $i$th *smallest* number.

Comment: Potato-Potahto. :) @RobPratt

Comment: One suggestion could be: Given $M$, let $m_1,\dots,m_{|M|} \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m_1>m_2>\dots>m_{|M|}$ be such that $M = \{m_1,\dots,m_{|M|}\} $. Then $m_i$ is the $i$-th greatest element of $M$. Or maybe a little less formal: Let $m_1,\dots,m_{|M|} \in \mathbb{N}$ be the elements of $M$, ordered descendingly.